# Detect inside a Gatsby plugin if the current project is using typescript?

Tags: typescript, gatsby

Is it possible? Maybe using something like https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#resolvableExtensions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hhhm perhaps you can hook into `onCreateWebpackConfig` & check the extensions there:

```js
// gatsby-node.js

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ getConfig }) => {
  const { extensions } = getConfig().resolve
  const hasTs = extensions.find(ext => ['.ts', '.tsx'].includes(ext))
  console.log(hasTs) // undefined if no ts
}
```

But if you need that information upfront, the most sure shot is to check if there are any ts files in `src` directory with something like `glob`

```js
const path = require(`path`)
const glob = require(`glob`)

const checkTs = ({ directory }) => {
  const srcFolder = path.join(directory, 'src')
  const tsFiles = glob.sync(`${srcFolder}/**/*.ts{,x}`)
  return (tsFiles.length > 0)
}

exports.onPreInit = ({ store }) => {
  const { directory } = store.getState().program
  const hasTs = checkTs({ directory })
  console.log({ hasTs })
}
```

I'm curious why you'd need this information though? If I were implementing a typescript-specific feature, I'd trust user to only use it if they use typescript.

Comment: thanks @Derek, I was building a plugin that is looking for default templates inside the project/src, assuming the use of some conventional folder structure. Instead of checking for multiple extensions (js, jsx, tsx) I was just curious to know if there was a way to determine if a gatsby project is using typescript. Thanks for your help!